# Windows 7 Gadget debugging with Visual Studio 2010

Tags: debugging, windows-7, windows-desktop-gadgets

i try to debug a windows gadget. Just-In-Time debugging fires up and i can see an VS2010IDE attached to the sidebar process. But there is no source code to debug! Only a blank file with the yellow debug pointer. What is my problem?

Configuration of my system is based on this article:
**Gadgets for Windows Sidebar Debugging** (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456467(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have posted on the MSDN forum about this.
I think script debugging is broken in studio 2010 beta2.

I cannot get script debugging to work on my ASP.NET MVC project either.
We get a blank page, and the IDE cannot find the code to debug.
Trying to open files in the Internet Explorer tree in solution exlorer results in blank files being opened.

I think it's a bug - and afterall it is a beta.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, and for a while I was thinking it might have to do with my machine being 64-bit, or a permissions issue, but I have no way of confirming it.

However, I was able to solve it by using the template on this Code Project site:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/gadgets/HeterodoxGadgetTemplate.aspx

The nice thing about the template is that it's setup as a Windows application.  When you run the app it handles the local deployment of your gadget and starts the sidebar service (sidebar.exe).  I believe this probably gets around a number of permissions issues.

After setting up a new project using this template, I was able to successfully debug the JavaScript using the "debugger" methods explained everywhere else (for example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb456467%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).